# Angular 2 - Function to select a component in a group

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I was wondering how I could solve a problem I'm having here. In a sign-up page, I have two buttons, that are components `<btn-gender>` where each of them displays a gender to be selected.

The problem is, I need to create a logic to understand each of them is selected. Remember that I also have a button for those who don't want to answer it. I could easily solve it using `<ion-select>` but I really need to use buttons as it is expected in a layout I'm following.

Do you guys have any suggestion of how I could solve it? Thanks

HTML:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <h4 text-center>Are you:</h4>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row >
      <ion-col>
        <btn-gender [text]="textMale" [imageURL]="imageMale" [(ngModel)]="male"></btn-gender>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <btn-gender [text]="textFemale" [imageURL]="imageFemale" [(ngModel)]="female"></btn-gender>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <button ion-button block>I prefer not to answer this</button>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <button ion-button block [disabled]="!isValid()" (click)="next()">Continue</button>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array and keep track of which are selected:

```
<ion-row >
  <ion-col>
    <btn-gender [text]="textMale" [imageURL]="imageMale" [(ngModel)]="genders" (click)="activate('male')"></btn-gender>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <btn-gender [text]="textFemale" [imageURL]="imageFemale" [(ngModel)]="genders" (click)="activate('female')"></btn-gender>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>

activate(gender: string): void {

  // Second condition included as per OP's own solution
  if (this.genders.indexOf(gender) === -1 && !this.genders.length) {
    this.genders.push(gender);
  }
  else {
    this.genders.splice(this.genders.indexOf(gender), 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm!!! Thanks @Chrillewoodz, the only thing I changed in the code above was adding a line to check if the array is empty, as it was adding two options. `activate(gender: string): void {
    if (this.genders.indexOf(gender) === -1 && this.genders.length === 0) {
      this.genders.push(gender);
    }
    else {
      this.genders.splice(this.genders.indexOf(gender), 1);
    }
  }`

Comment: Sweet, don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful. I'll update the answer to include your fix.